# Prove that $\forall A \exists !B\forall C (\forall x[(x\in C\land x\notin A)\iff (x\in C \land x\in B )])$

Tags: logic, proof-writing

This is Velleman's exercise 3.6.8.a (rephrased).

> Suppose that $\mathscr P (U)$ is the power set of the set $U$. Prove that $\forall A \in \mathscr P (U)\exists !B\in \mathscr P (U)\forall C \in \mathscr P (U)(\forall x[(x\in C\land x\notin A)\iff (x\in C \land x\in B )])$

I am stuck on this one. Can't even come up with an appropriate set $B$. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer in a more 'calculational' style.  Using slightly different logical notations (see [EWD1300](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/transcriptions/EWD13xx/EWD1300.html)),$
\newcommand{\calc}{\begin{align} \quad &}
\newcommand{\op}[1]{\\ #1 \quad & \quad \unicode{x201c}}
\newcommand{\hints}[1]{\mbox{#1} \\ \quad & \quad \phantom{\unicode{x201c}} }
\newcommand{\hint}[1]{\mbox{#1} \unicode{x201d} \\ \quad & }
\newcommand{\endcalc}{\end{align}}
\newcommand{\ref}[1]{\text{(#1)}}
\newcommand{\P}[1]{\mathscr P(#1)}
\newcommand{\true}{\text{true}}
$ you are trying to rewrite
$$
\tag 0
B\in \P{U} \;\land\; \langle \forall C : C \in \P{U} : \langle \forall x :: x \in C \land x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in C \land x \in B \rangle \rangle
$$
in the form $\;B = \ldots\;$.

Let's see how far we get rewriting the main part of $\ref 0$:

$$\calc
    \langle \forall C : C \in \P{U} : \langle \forall x :: x \in C \land x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in C \land x \in B \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{logic: extract common conjunct $\;x \in C\;$ out of $\;\equiv\;$}
         \hint{-- to move $\;x \in C\;$ closer to the other occurrences of $\;C\;$}
    \langle \forall C : C \in \P{U} : \langle \forall x : x \in C : x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in B \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{logic: merge quantifications; definition of $\;\P{\cdot}\;$}
    \langle \forall C,x : x \in C \subseteq U : x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in B \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{set theory: simplify quantifications}
    \langle \forall x : x \in U : x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in B \rangle
\op\equiv\hints{logic: reintroduce common conjunct $\;x \in U\;$}
         \hint{-- working towards $\;\langle \forall x :: \ldots \;\equiv\; x \in B \rangle\;$ and extensionality}
    \langle \forall x :: x \in U \land x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in U \land x \in B \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{simplify RHS using $\;B \in \P{U}\;$ or equivalently $\;B \subseteq U\;$}
    \langle \forall x :: x \in U \land x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in B \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{extensionality}
    U \setminus A \;=\; B
\endcalc$$

That leaves us with the obligation to show that this $\;B\;$ satisfies the first part of $\ref 0$, $\;B \in \P{U}\;$, which is simple.

Note that we did not need to use the assumption that $\;A \in \P{U}\;$.

---

To formally wrap things up, we conclude
$$\calc
    \langle \forall A :: \langle \exists! B : B\in \P{U} \;\land\; \langle \forall C : C \in \P{U} : \langle \forall x :: x \in C \land x \notin A \;\equiv\; x \in C \land x \in B \rangle \rangle \rangle \rangle
\op\equiv\hint{by the above calculation; $\;U \setminus A \in \P{U}\;$}
    \langle \forall A :: \langle \exists! B : B \;=\; U \setminus A \rangle \op\equiv\hint{by definition, $\;\langle \exists! B : B \;=\; \ldots \rangle \;\equiv\; \true\;$}
    \true
\endcalc$$

Comment: I believe the definition of $\mathscr P$ is irrelevant to the problem at hand, it could have been any function.

Comment: @DanielV Well, replacing $\;\mathscr P(U)\;$ by $\;\emptyset\;$ in $\text{(0)}$ makes it false.  And the same if $\;U \not= \emptyset\;$ and replacing it by $\;\{U\}\;$.  So we cannot choose _any_ function.

Comment: Ah right, non empty universe, good point.

Comment: It's great to see a calculational answer! How is the uniqueness part of the exercise proved?

Comment: @Adam I've added another paragraph, hopefully that clears things up?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

What happens if I take $C=U$? That should give you a good idea about what $B$ should be (as a "function" of $A$).

Answer (score 1):

You might try $B = U \setminus A$.